# Does lazy='joined' mean eager load?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Am I understanding correctly that the way to declare that a relationship be eager loaded is with `lazy='joined' or lazy='subquery'`?

"lazy" is the opposite of "eager" — is it a historical quirk and/or bad design that the "lazy" keyword is used to signify eager loading in this case, or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Alternatively, you can use [`.options`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.options) on the query, which gives you more flexibility.

It's a historical artifact. If you look at the [relevant code from 0.5.0](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/src/0e79d6e28ea8e68a4ee4a58c138115608a30e41b/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/__init__.py?at=cython&fileviewer=file-view-default#__init__.py-276), the only options were `True`, `False`, `None`, and `"dynamic"`.

I agree that it's a bit of a misnomer. Something like `load_strategy` would probably be better.

Comment: It's a complete misnomer :D